# Cannot open managed package tab in Sandbox

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, tab

I have installed our managed package in our client's Sandbox org. When I tried to open the Configuration page which is added on the tab of the package, I am getting below error message.

> The value of the "" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

[image]

The same app same version is installed in my developer edition org which is working fine. I am able to open the tab over there and there is no error on the page as well.

**EDIT**

This is the page URL https://customdomain--packagename.visualforce.com/apex/vfpagename?sfdc.tabName=01rO0000000Abts

Comment: Can you post the complete URL to the page?

Comment: @rael_kid I have added the URL in the question.

Comment: I've been searching around, and this error can apparently be caused by a lot of different things. For instance: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165824/the-value-of-the-parameter-contains-a-character-that-is-not-allowed-or-the-va but also https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DmLrQAK The latter has to do with licenses, but the former with the length of a field name. Of course, because you installed your app, the namespace is prefixed to the fields, which could make them too long. Maybe you can grant login access, and login through the Subscriber so you can see logs

Comment: @rael_kid Thanks that is really helpful, I really wonder why I didn't come across that question which was already there in SFSE.

Comment: @rael_kid how I can grant login access?

Comment: @rael_kid thanks your comment really helped me, I was able to login into the Subscriber org from License Management App, there I got the debug logs, found that there was an exception.

Comment: Good to hear that you were able to get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged into the Subscriber org from License Management App, there I got the debug logs, found that there was an exception.

Here are the steps to get a debug log from Subscriber org.

1. Grant login access to package vendor from the subscriber org.
2. Log in to Packaging org -> goto License Management app -> Subscribers -> Search the 
   Subscribers from the list using Org Id or name.
3. Set debug logs or open developer console.
4. Perform the test and get debug logs.